# Fitting three parameter log-normal distribution in R

Tags: r, distribution

I want to fit three parameter log-normal distribution (See [here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/users/f/k/fkv/2009-06-lognor-csda.pdf) for reference) in R.

My MWE is below:

```
set.seed(12345)
library(FAdist)
X <- rlnorm3(n=100, shape = 2, scale = 1.5, thres = 1)

# m: Location Parameter
# s: Scale Parameter
# t: Threshold Parameter
LL3 <- function(X, m, s, t)(1/((X-t)*s*(2*pi)^0.5))*exp(((-(log(X-t)-m)^2)/(2*s^2)))

library(MASS)
fitdistr(x=X, densfun=LL3, start=list(m=2, s=1.5, t=1))
```

But this code throws the following error message:

```
Error in stats::optim(x = c(30.9012208754183, 223.738029433835,
46.4287558537441,  :    non-finite finite-difference value [3] In addition: Warning message: In log(X - t) : NaNs produced
```

Is there any R package to fit three parameter distributions like three parameter `Log-normal`, `Gamma`, `Weibull`, and `Log-logistic distributions`?

Comment: The error message is consistent with having `t>=X`, resulting in `log(X-t)` not being defined. Could you try to set some constraints to your optimization, by using the optional argument `upper=` in the call to `fitdistr`? Alternatively, you could rewrite your function `LL3` so that it returns 0 when `t>=X`.

Comment: Thanks @Jealie for your answer. Would you mind to suggest any changes in the code. Thanks

Comment: `LL3 <- function(X, m, s, t)ifelse(t>=X,0,(1/((X-t)*s*(2*pi)^0.5))*exp(((-(log(X-t)-m)^2)/(2*s^2))))`

Comment: Thanks @Jealie for your help. Your provide code also throws errors.

Comment: @Jealie also, there should be strict greater than according to the paper. `ifelse(t>X,0...`. It still the same error though unfortunately.

Comment: @Csislander: Actually you need to catch the case in which t==X, because log(0) is not defined. Otherwise, I am unable to test the expression myself, but I bet that the warning disappeared and was replaced by something else?

Comment: @Jealie You're right, I was thinking of it backwards, but the same error persists in either case.

Comment: As another quick error spot, the function `rllog3` produces a 3 parameter log-logistic, rather than a log-normal (`rlnorm3`)

Comment: @Csislander: Good catch and it also resolve the issue of error.

Comment: Since it resolved it, I updated my answer to include the information from these comments for people who might find this question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it looks as though `dlnorm3` (which is built into the `FAdist` package) already returns a zero probability when `x<=thres`, so plugging `dlnorm3` straight into `fitdistr` appears to work fine:

```
set.seed(12345)
library(FAdist)
library(MASS)
X <- rlnorm3(n=100, shape = 2, scale = 1.5, thres = 1)
fitdistr(X,dlnorm3,start=list(shape = 2, scale = 1.5, thres = 1))
```

Results:

```
     shape        scale        thres   
  2.31116615   1.94366899   1.02798643 
 (0.18585476) (0.23426764) (0.01480906)
```

This does fail if we use the `rllog3` function to generate values (we get much more extreme values):

```
Y <- rllog3(n=100, shape = 2, scale = 1.5, thres = 1)
fitdistr(Y,dlnorm3,start=list(shape = 2, scale = 1.5, thres = 1),
            method="Nelder-Mead")
## Error in stats::optim(x = c(10.1733112422871, 
##       310.508398424974, 1.08946140904075,  : 
##  non-finite finite-difference value [3]
```

Using `debug(optim)`, it appears that if we switch to Nelder-Mead we can postpone the problem until the Hessian is computed.

If we use `bbmle::mle2` instead we can get at least get the coefficients (with a warning that the Hessian can't be inverted ...)

```
library(bbmle)
mle2(Y~dlnorm3(m,s,t),
     data=data.frame(Y),
     start=list(m= 2, s = 1.5, t = 1),
         method="Nelder-Mead")


## Call:
## mle2(minuslogl = Y ~ dlnorm3(m, s, t), start = list(m = 2, s = 1.5, 
##     t = 1), method = "Nelder-Mead", data = data.frame(Y))

## Coefficients:
##        m        s        t 
## 4.227529 1.606202 1.001115 

## Log-likelihood: -440.27 
## Warning message:
## In mle2(Y ~ dlnorm3(m, s, t), data = data.frame(Y), start = list(m = 2,  :
##   couldn't invert Hessian
```

Comment: Wow, much much simplified. Thanks

Comment: There is a typo in `Y <- rllog3(n=100, shape = 2, scale = 1.5, thres = 1)
fitdistr(Y,dlnorm3,start=list(shape = 2, scale = 1.5, thres = 1),
            method="Nelder-Mead")`. `dlnorm3` should be replaced by `dllog3`.

Comment: actually, I intended to fit with `dlnorm3`.  The point is to see how you can get the model to fit even if the data are weird/the model is misspecified.

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that there was problem in estimating the gradient of objective function. There are several reasons this could happen, but the most likely is that one of the parameters are becoming negative or causing negative values during the distribution fitting/optimization process (likely your threshold parameter becoming larger than your lognormal variable, in which case, the distribution should be 0 at those points... unfortunately, `fitdistr` doesn't know that).

The best way to fix this kind of problem is either to try different starting parameters or perhaps find a way to make the distribution be 0 in these cases within `fitdistr`.

Edit: Additionally, the code has other errors, so try, as Jealie suggested:

```
LL3 <- function(X, m, s, t)ifelse(t>=X,0,(1/((X-t)*s*(2*pi)^0.5))*exp(((-(log(X-t)-m)^2)/(2*s^2))))
```

and `rlnorm3` rather than `rllog3`

Comment: Thanks @Csislander for your answer. Would you mind to suggest any changes in the code. Thanks

Comment: Wonder how to put constraint S>0 in `fitdistr`.

Comment: I believe there is a `lower` argument that is passed to the optim function that takes an input vector of lower bounds for your parameters. See: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/optim.html