# Fitting a three parameters Gamma distribution in R

Tags: r

I have this sample

```
Qord<-c(4650,3270,3186,2620,2460,2200,2068,2045,2040,1966,1860,1842,1612,1535,1420,1400,1380,1375,1370,1320,1280,1260,1120,1040,1020,989,901,889,830,796,785,727,630,604,447,435,334,276,275)
```

I want to fit to it a three parameters Gamma distribution like the dgamma3 from FAdist package.
I followed the example from “https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631746/fitting-three-parameter-log-normal-distribution-in-r” as:

```
library(FAdist)
library(MASS)
rzlt<-fitdistr(Qord,dgamma3,start=list(shape = 10, scale = 15, thres = min(Qord)))
```

I get this error:
Error in stats::optim(x = c(4650, 3270, 3186, 2620, 2460, 2200, 2068,  :
initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
Please, can someone show me what can be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `thres = 0` and see what happens

Comment: Use the MME estimates for the dgamma distribution as the starting point. If you do not want much stress use base R instead of the packages to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Note that you just need to specify a good starting point since you are using `BFGS` method:

```
xbar <- mean(Qord)
vr <- var(Qord)
MASS::fitdistr(Qord,FAdist::dgamma3,
            start=list(shape=xbar^2/vr, scale=vr/xbar, thres=0))
     shape        scale        thres   
    2.441947   555.627973    72.145260 
 (  1.753323) (268.008445) (343.161094)
```

Where did I get the formulas `xbar^2/vr` and `vr/xbar`? Used the MME estimates for shape and scale in gamma distribution.

Now we could easily accomplish the same in Base R:

```
optim(c(xbar^2/vr, vr/xbar, 0),\(x)
   -sum(dgamma(Qord - x[3], x[1], scale=x[2], log = TRUE)),
   method = 'BFGS'
 )
$par
[1]   2.441947 555.627847  72.145175

$value
[1] 314.2993
```

What if you did not know where to begin? Better use the Nelder-Mead approach. Just to point out, the values obtained by `fitdistr` above are technically not globally optimal. We can find values better than these eg the values `1.665947 742.025432 206.362983` give a greater Likelihood than the ones obtained above.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. 
1. How did you get the idea to choose threshold value as zero?
2. I'll add a question. Studying in the web I saw that sometimes it is preferred to scale the values in the sample, for example dividing them by the maximum value. It is said that optimization algorithms prefer such scaled values. Is it then consistent that after obtaining its parameters they are scaled back, multiplying them for example by the maximum value?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nicolai the choice of `threshold` should be a number less than all the numbers. Since the data is positive, i just chose 0. Note that you should have a number less than the minimum. Not equal to the minimum. ie `x>thres`. The obvious choice is 0. Also Yes you can do the scaling.